# Can I make Win10 file explorer's preview pane larger than half the screen?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm using the preview pane in Win10's file explorer to look through a large number of files. But the text is small so I'd like to make the pane bigger. I've tried dragging the center line of the window but the biggest I can make the pane is 50% of the maximized file explorer window.  Is there any way to make it bigger?

EDIT:  I've added a screenshot.  The words "Sample Text" are at about the middle of the screen where the preview window starts.  I'd like to have that point move further to the left.[image]

Comment: I do not understand exactly.  File Explorer screens cannot be larger that File Explorer, so just make it is large as you need. Then make Text size larger (Settings, Display) and scroll as needed.

Comment: @John the OP probably means larger than half the window

Comment: Just make all of Explorer larger. It will go full screen if needed and any size wanted

Comment: As suggested by John, I have tried maximizing the Explorer window, but that does not solve the problem.  Please see the screen shot I just added for a better explanation of what I'm seeing - thx

Comment: If you have maximized the Explorer screen, then all you can do now to make text bigger (as you ask in your question) is to use Text Size in System, Display.

Comment: Also if there is an impediment seeing text when the app is full screen, in addition to text size as already mentioned, also use the screen magnifier

Comment: I am running 22H2 and don't see this limitation (I just tried).  I can get 80% of all preview when maximized.  I would guess that the math is tied to the current resolution.  Mine is 3440x1440.